# How to capture user login Wireshark

Tags: windows, server, active-directory, wireshark, domaincontroller

I want to simulate the user domain login to his windows machine, and then capture the traffic in Wireshark
So, I create a new user in the active directory and then open Wireshark and run the following command

```
net use \\dc1.KTG.local /user:tstr@ktg.local password
```

The command is successful but I didn’t get any traffic captured in Wireshark
And I need Kerberos traffic to be seen in Wireshark while user log in

Comment: No traffic at all? Make sure your capture is configured correctly.

Comment: @Anders it captures traffic when I browse websites, for example. But when run the command as login user it doesn't capture anything

Comment: The credential is cached locally?

Comment: @Anders yes, and I noticed that when using the net command in any action, the Wireshark doesn't capture it.